# joomla create component with creation of 2 tables

Tags: joomla

I try to create 2 tables for a component I m writing for joomla. I have in the xml file:

```
<install> <!-- Runs on install -->
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install1.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install2.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
</install>
```

But it installs only the first file hence the first table. And if I put all the sql commands in one line I get an error from joomla:
JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for the help,

John.

Comment: Why don't you merge the contents of `install1.mysql.utf8.sql` and `install2.mysql.utf8.sql` so they are in 1 big file? Would make more sense

Comment: In fact I tried but then I get the error JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Comment: can you please provide your entire XML file and state what version of Joomla you're using? I think I know what the problem might be but just need confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I found the problem. In fact, I was using the wrong collation in my database :(

Comment: For sure you should be able to have such a field in your table. Please post you whole sql file, I guess it is invalid.

Comment: That's not right — we have lots of products that use userid, and it's not Joomla that's having the problem its the SQL.

Comment: You are totally right, I just discovered that I used the wrong collation in my db and that messed up everything. I will edit my answer.